# Python test "framework" for testing input files and their outputs

Tags: python, testing, end-to-end

I'm writing end-to-end tests for my tool, which is written in Python. The tool reads a file as input. I want to test its exit code, and its output.

This is a fairly common idiom, and I've seen it done in several ways. In the PHP project, each test is a file, and has lines like: `INPUT:`, `EXPECTED:`, `EXPECTED_REGEX:`, etc. In my own [phc](http://phpcompiler.org) project, each file is a normal source file, but with a comment added to the top, which includes keywords like `EXPECTED`. I think I had copied that off [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org) which uses a much more complex tool written in tcl.

Are there frameworks, libraries, etc, that do this in Python? It should:

- read the source file
- parse special keywords (or similar) corresponding to expected output, exit code, words/regexes it expects to find or not find,
- check that the output is correct.

While it doesn't seem hard in theory, I recall lots of edge-cases (esp involving escaping) when implementing this before, and would rather not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The robot framework might be helpful. It is a keyword driven functional testing tool implemented in python and can be extended with pythion or java.

see: http://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/tags/robotframework-2.5.4/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html

There are a number of built in libraries that you might be able to apply to solve your problem, including a OperatingSystem library for working with files etc. and a Strings library for working with strings:

http://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/tags/robotframework-2.5.4/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#standard-libraries

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a http://pythonpaste.org/scripttest/ library by Ian Bicking.

Answer (score 0):

Since the implementation of file io is system dependent, why not mock out the file reading and writing using StringIO:

http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html

and then test the bulk of the logic (reading from a file, doing some stuff, writing to a file) in python?

Then, perhaps you could have one end to end test for basic sanity by having a separate python file call out to the script using the `commands` module or something similar where you are calling out to it as another process:

http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html

Using that you could get both the output, and the status.

Comment: Judging from your answer, I believe I may have misstated the question. I've rewritten most of it, and hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: oh I see now, well looks like Mark has your answer :)